# how to convert existing xcode project to static library

Tags: ios

I am trying to add MWPhotoBrowser source code from github to my own project. For adding that i need to add mwphotobrowser.a file in "Link binary libraries". Any one help to convert the source code of MWPhotoBrowser to get mwphotobrowser.a file.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: If you are adding the source code, why do you need the .a file?

Comment: i need to add it as static library into my own project. I need to do the photo gallery like in the link https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser. so i try to add to it as static library.

Comment: But you said you are adding the source code. If you add the source code (.h and .m files) you don't need the .a file.

Comment: is it possible to create static library from swift project ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new target of Static Library in your Project Settings. You can follow below mentioned links:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

https://medium.com/@jigarm/creating-a-static-library-in-objective-c-ios-75e4fc5eb41a

I have used this in one of my project and it is working well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to create static librart from swift project ?

Comment: No. As of Xcode 8.2.1 it is not possible. But you can create a framework.